# Javascript Regex optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have two JQuery/Javascript functions that highlights all string occurences in a web page, and then narrows these occurences one by one when clicking on the next/prev buttons.
Here is the current JS code for the next and previous buttons:

```
    var outputHtmlContent;
    var posScroll = 0;

    // Trigger on search next occurence's button
    $('#nextSearchOutputButton').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchString = "Command Name";
        $("body").highlight(searchString);
        $(".highlight").css({ backgroundColor: "#E0FFFF" });
        var regex = /Command Name/g, result, indices = [];
        var i = 0;
        outputHtmlContent = $("#output").html();
        if (posScroll == outputHtmlContent.match(/Command Name/g).length - 1) posScroll = 0;
        else
            posScroll++;
        while ((result = regex.exec(outputHtmlContent))) {
            if (posScroll == i) {
                var index = result.index;
                outputHtmlContent = outputHtmlContent.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + outputHtmlContent.substring(index, index + searchString.length) + "</span>" + outputHtmlContent.substring(index + searchString.length);
                $("#output").html(outputHtmlContent);
                document.getElementById("commandNumber" + posScroll).scrollIntoView();
                return;
            }
            i++;
        }
    })

    // Trigger on search previous occurence's button
    $('#prevSearchOutputButton').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchString = "Command Name";
        $("body").highlight(searchString);
        $(".highlight").css({ backgroundColor: "#E0FFFF" });
        var regex = /Command Name/g, result, indices = [];
        var i = 0;
        outputHtmlContent = $("#output").html();
        if (posScroll == 0) posScroll = outputHtmlContent.match(/Command Name/g).length - 1;
        else
            posScroll--;
        while ((result = regex.exec(outputHtmlContent)) && i <= posScroll) {
            if (posScroll == i) {
                var index = result.index;
                outputHtmlContent = outputHtmlContent.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + outputHtmlContent.substring(index, index + searchString.length) + "</span>" + outputHtmlContent.substring(index + searchString.length);
                $("#output").html(outputHtmlContent);
                document.getElementById("commandNumber" + posScroll).scrollIntoView();
                return;
            }
            i++;
        }
    })
```

The two functions work well, but I have a very critical issue concerning the time spent when executing the two functions, this time estimated to *10 seconds* for *IE* when moving from one occurence to an other and is estimated to *4 seconds* for *FF and chrome*.
I googled and found that the Regex performance issue is a classic topic. I found this nice atricle http://infrequently.org/2007/02/regexs-are-slow/. 
I would rather remove completely this feature than offering it with such a low quality issue. Yet, I want to stick on it because it is very helpful for my user. Can anyone help improve the Regex performance for my functions ?

Comment: Why would you use regex in this scenario?

Comment: As mentioned before, I want to find all string occurences of the word Command Name in a div. You can check the two search functions, it is the line while ((result = regex.exec(outputHtmlContent))) { that executes the Regex on the base string containg the div's html.

Comment: Yes, but why _are_ you using regex to match a static string? You can simply use the [`string.replace`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/replace)

Comment: But I want to get all the indexes for all the occurences of a substring in an array. Something like array[0]=158, array[1]=587... The array contains all the indexes with their positions. I always thought that replace just replaces a string by an other. Can you please tell me how to generate the same array with replace? This would really help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see you using the array of positions in your program. Can you provide a jsfiddle and explain a little more clearly about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What I am trying to do is : Get the occurences of a substring in a div element. Then, get the positions of every string, and highlight it (like ctrl+F shortcut in every browser). For that, I NEED to have the positions of every substring in order to highlight the texts one after one. The next button jumps to the next occurence, the previous jump to the previous occurence.